# Resharper: Code Style Sharing - Enforcing

Tags: .net, resharper, coding-style, stylecop

We have a team of 40+ engineers working on a common code base. We're using resharper, and have been sharing our suggested settings by having a 'definitive' configuration file emailed out which people can import.

However, as time goes on we wish to tighten up on various things on new versions and new work, without requiring refactoring on older things.

We believe that using the option for settings being shared per-solution in a file for Resharper settings works nicely.

We can add .resharper files to our solution folders, and mark them in SVN as only writeable by our coding standards authorities.

However, the mere prescience of one of these files doesn't have a Resharper instance use it unless you turn on that option, in which case, the file is overwritten with the current settings. And if you turn off the option Resharper deletes the file.

Is there anyway we can trigger Resharper to switch to the right mode and use the file without attempting to destroy it?

Similarly, is there a good way to trigger Resharper + StyleCop to use the appropriate project specific StyelCop settings files we wish to provide?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re: StyleCop, having a Settings.StyleCop file in the project should be enough for StyleCop (and StyleCop For ReSharper) to use those settings instead of the global settings.